# JQuery and PHP - how to show comments for a single post from a database?

Tags: php, jquery, database, comments

The below code shows a div when the link is clicked, however it opens every comment div for every post on my news feed page. Is there a way to open only the comments div that relates to its news post in particular?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Avinash</title>

<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="comments">Show Comments</a>
<br />
<div class="toggleComments" style="display:none;">
  This is #comment1 <br />
  This is #comment2 <br />
  This is #comment3 <br />
  This is #comment4 <br />
  This is #comment5 <br />
  This is #comment6
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var toggle = false;
$(function() {
    $('a.comments').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.toggleComments').toggle(500,function() {
      if(!toggle) {
        $this.text('Hide Comments');
        toggle = !toggle;
      }else {
        $this.text('Show Comments');
        toggle = !toggle;
      }
    });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your comments are a monolithic blob of text. each comment would need to be individually wrapped so you can toggle that particular wrapper. right now at most you can toggle the #toggleComments div only.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to link the show comments link to the post id. 
Maybe something like Show comments and then access that in your javascript.

You would need to list all the comments inside another section/div that relates to the postid so you can differentiate the different post comments.

Comment: How could I add the post ID to jquery?